# How can a kafka producer persist the published avro messages to a database?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I want to be able to persist the published messages in avro format to the database after I have I published them.

How is it possible from a kafka publisher to get access to the published avro message so that you can persist it?

Answer (score 1):

You need a consumer once the data is in Kafka; otherwise there is no point in having a producer if you are just going to immediately write the record somewhere else. But yes, you called `send` with record content, so you can re-use the same POJO in any other client afterwards...

If you must use Kafka, you should try to use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html) for this (Confluent maintains an AvroConverter plugin that works with their KafkaAvroSerializer, if you don't use this, you need to write your own  Converter implementation). In other words, "read your writes", don't implement "two phase commits" on different systems. E.g. What if Kafka or the database is down / slow to write, which "wins" or is the "source of truth"?

And avoid writing to a database "as Avro". Use actual datatypes available to the database (parse the record, which is what Connect can do)

Comment: Indeed using a consumer seems a good approach. Is there a reason to avoid writing to the database as avro. I have requirement to be able to provide all messages in avro-format available for download. I guess that would be e.g. one merged file per month, with each message appended to the same db blob record. There is no requirement to query the database. I think the goal is to be able to replay the messages afterwards and also be able to extract the schema out of each. Would there be a more suitable format for that?

Comment: Use a filesystem, not a database for archival purposes. Do you have access to S3, or are willing to run MinIO as a replacement? https://blog.min.io/kafka-schema-registry/