# How could Kafka Connect help persisting Avro to a database and why is this a good design approach?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, avro

According to [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76830859/15552149) Kafka Connect would help prevent performing a "2-step commit" when publishing to Kafka and persisting the avro message to a database, and that it follows a "read your writes" design approach.

I don't see how this happens. How is that different to extending my `KafkaAvroSerializer` and extract the "bytearray" containing the avro message and then after publishing it, persist it to the database.

I get that the approach that I suggest creates the issue of not knowing what to prioritise when something goes wrong on either the db or Kafka, BUT I don't see how the Kafka Connect way doesn't face the same exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for finding my other answer. The difference is that you're describing two phase commits, which isn't what Kafka Connect does.

At a high level, Kafka Connect (for sink connectors, such as to a database) is built on top of the Consumer API, and doing exactly what you've described (with KafkaAvroDeserializer, assuming you've setup AvroConverter). But it offers builtin scalability and fault tolerance mechanism, and config driven (no coding required, if not needing any custom plugins).

Worth pointing out that KafkaAvroDeserializer doesn't return a byte array of the Avro record

The alternative approach of "read your writes" is called the "Outbox Pattern" w/ CDC; you write to your database, then use Debezium (built on Connect API) to *read the database*, then write to Kafka. This has the added benefit of consistent database transactions and durability

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for the quick response. By "fault tolerance mechanism" do you mean that, in case of error in either the Kafka or the DB, it will perform a rollback both on the Kafka publishment and on the DB transaction?

Comment: I've not used the JDBC Sink connector in-depth, but I think it uses transactions and will do rollbacks, but I was referring more to the `errors.tolerance` config option in the Connect framework. And no, Connect sinks are only consumrers; they cannot affect producer logic (data is already in the topic for it to work)

Comment: Let's assume that my project's requirements are that a message needs to be published to kafka and persisted to a db, and if one of them can't happen, both of them shouldn't happen. What shall I use then so that in case my db dies the requirements can be covered? Can Kafka Connect handle that somehow?

Comment: Sure. Use transactions, and only write to one location. Kafka would be more highly available, so I recommend writing there. Then use Kafka Connect, like I said, to write to the database... If the Kafka client transaction fails, nothing arrives at the database. It'll work the exact same way if you were to write a database transaction and use Debezium (i.e. Kafka Connect) to write to Kafka. Do not wrap two transactions in each other (two phase commits)